# How do I use the luminance in an image to control the opacity of a fill in SVG

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I would like to use an [image](http://lightartpixel.com/FILTER_pencil.png) to control the alpha channel of a fill in SVG.

I can't figure out the right way to combine SourceGraphic with the alpha. Here is what I have right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <defs>
       <filter id="FILTER_pencil" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
         <feImage result="result1" width="128" height="128" xlink:href="http://lightartpixel.com/FILTER_pencil.png"/>
         <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" result="alpha" in="result1"/>
         <feComposite operator="atop" in="alpha" in2="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
       </filter>
     </defs>
     <rect fill="#5d496a" stroke="#5d496a" filter="url(#FILTER_pencil)" width="100" height="100"/>
  </svg>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/combinatorial/4EhPh/2/) is a jsfiddle that shows the current output. Which seems to be combining the luminance with the fill color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use atop, that renders both the black shape with variable opacity that you got from the luminanceToAlpha as well as the source graphic. Instead, you want to use the "in" operator, which only renders the source graphic, but uses the alpha values from the luminanceToAlpha as alpha. You also need to reverse the order of your "ins". This gets you what you want.

```
<feComposite operator="in" in2="alpha" in="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
```

Comment: The problem with this is it now ignores the color of the rect, I want the color to come from the rect fill, and the alpha to come from the luminance map. I have updated the fiddle so that the rect is red to make this clearer... http://jsfiddle.net/combinatorial/4EhPh/3/

Comment: Read my answer again. You have to change the in2 to alpha and the in to SourceGraphic.